# IBM MobileFirst Android - When to connect to to the MFP Server with multiple activities

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I am building a new application with the MobileFirst Server from IBM.

In order to connect to the server you need to create a WLClient instance using `WLClient.createInstance(context);`

Subsequent calls can then use `WLClient.getInstance()` for communication to the MFP Server

What I don't understand is the WLClient.createInstance(Context context) method. I tried creating a helper class that manages this WLClient instance using my application context, but I get a log message saying I should be passing in my Activies context.

Does this mean I need to create and connect to the MFP Server for every activity? This doesn't make sense to me, and i'm hoping someone who has experienced this issue can shed some light on it.

Answer (score 0):

It is expected that you call `WLClient.createInstance(context);` once in Main activity of your app, like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    client = WLClient.createInstance(this);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that hold onto my MainActivity context throughout the life of my application even after it is destroyed?

Comment: during the call context.getApplicationContext() is used

Comment: That's interesting, why would I get that log message about the activity context when I try to pass in the AppContext directly?